# Check / Uncheck All but one checkbox.?

Tags: javascript, select, checkbox

Currently I'm using this to check / uncheck all checkboxes in my form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
checked=false;
function checkedAll (frm1) {
    var aa= document.getElementById('frm1');
     if (checked == false)
          {
           checked = true
          }
        else
          {
          checked = false
          }
    for (var i =0; i < aa.elements.length -2; i++) 
    {
     aa.elements[i].checked = checked;
    }
      }
</script>
```

This works well, But I have one check box within this form I don't want to be affected.

It has an id of  `id='ignore'` is there anyway the above code can be used to work as is, but ignore this one checkbox ?

Thanks

Comment: can you post your html code part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (var i =0; i < aa.elements.length -2; i++) 
    {
        if(aa.elements[i].id !== 'ignore'){
             aa.elements[i].checked = checked;
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the if loop also...
The full code -

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var checked = false;

function checkedAll (frm1) {
    var chkBoxs = document.getElementById('frm1').getElementsByTagName('input');

    checked = !checked;

    for (var i =0; i < chkBoxs.length -2; i++) {
        if (chkBoxs[i].id == 'ignore') {
            continue;
        }
        chkBxs[i].checked = checked;
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i =0; i < aa.elements.length -2; i++) 
{
if (aa.elements[i].getAttribute('id') != 'ignore')
 aa.elements[i].checked = checked;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i =0; i < aa.elements.length -2; i++) 
{
if (aa.elements[i].getAttribute('id') == 'ignore') 
continue;
 aa.elements[i].checked = checked;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
checked=false;
function checkedAll (frm1) {
    var aa= document.getElementById('frm1');
     if (checked == false)
          {
           checked = true
          }
        else
          {
          checked = false
          }
     for (var i =0; i < aa.elements.length -2; i++) 
       {
         if (aa.elements[i].getAttribute('id') == 'ignore') 
             aa.elements[i].checked = false;
         else
             aa.elements[i].checked = checked;
     }
      }
</script>
```